# галочка у checkbox неправильно устанавливается при удалении элемента из массива TODOS

Tags: javascript, css, html5, reactjs

Всем привет, делаю своё первое приложение  TODOS на реакт и на финальном этапе выскочил неприятный баг со стилями который уже замучился исправлять. В общем при добавлении нового элемента в массив todos и последующим его удалении всё работает хорошо. Так же всё работает при клике на checkbox, а именно устанавливается галочка и зачёркивается текст. Это я реализовал с помощью вот этого кода в компоненте который рендерит li
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Переключение completed в элементе todo осуществляется с помощью этого кода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

НО как только я поставлю галочку и удалю любой элемент из списка вылазит вот такой баг.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При том что свойство completed у элементов в консоли выглядит вот так :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input checked={todo.completed} onChange={onChange(todo.title)} type="checkbox"/>
```

Comment: Ура! Заработало! Спасибо Вам большое,  искренне желаю Вам всех благ!